# QtConsole in anaconda

Tags: python

Whenever I try to Open qtconsole through Anaconda this is the message it shows can someone tell me how to fix this?
[The error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBIdc.png)

Comment: try to install pyside in conda, `conda install -c conda-forge pyside`

Comment: I tried that bt it says that there is failed to do with that repodata trying the next repodata and then it just tried to do it with the next one but it still failed